# Google realtime API and CodeMirror/Ace

Tags: javascript

My goal is to build a web site where my students will be able to work on web developing projects.

The problem is that it does not seem possible to use the Google Realtime API (so edits are parallel), but at the same time to gain from source editors like CodeMirror or Ace.

However these editors will transform the textarea to something not compatible with Google Realtime API which only works in `<textarea>` or `<input>`.

Anyone has faced a similar problem so far and can suggest anything?

For example, CodeMirror's

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea);
```

and this is no longer a text area. The following google sample won't work:

```
  // Connects the text boxes to the collaborative string
  function wireTextBoxes(collaborativeString) {
    var textArea1 = document.getElementById('text_area_1');
    var textArea2 = document.getElementById('text_area_2');
      var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea1); // duh
      gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(collaborativeString, textArea1);
    gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(collaborativeString, textArea2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [Firepad](https://github.com/firebase/firepad) (based on Firebase). It doesn't use google realtime api though, but provides collaborative editing, integrated with codemirror/ace.

Answer (score 1):

On github, there are already a lot of projects that seem to achieve what you are trying to do.

Instead of starting from scratch, what might be helpful is looking at this example on github and trying to get those to work first: [space editor](https://github.com/chaoscollective/Space_Editor)

The reason why your code example isn't working could be of many different reasons. One reason it might not work is because the javascript is running before all the html is loaded (so you would need to have a document.ready function wrapped around it first):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function wireTextBoxes(collaborativeString) {
var textArea1 = document.getElementById('text_area_1');
var textArea2 = document.getElementById('text_area_2');
  var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea1); // duh
  gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(collaborativeString, textArea1);
gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(collaborativeString, textArea2);
}

});
```

Could you post your html file as well? That could help with debugging. You also never call your function by the way.